# How to get logs and display them on a web using Java (basic Java)

Tags: java

I have logs that I want to show on a web browser. ( The source code is using **Log4j** for logging.)  I know where the logs are created. I want to code in java to display them on a web.

Can you give me some tips on **Java** coding ? (what class or API do I use to read the logs and display them)

Comment: Is it a project to learn more about Java or do you just want to get the data? If it is the latter, I would look into logstash https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash.

Comment: @Frederic Klein I want to learn more about Java. if there are many ways to get the data and display them I want to know. I'll definitely look at your link. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple solution**: You can go ahead creating a Controller which can read from the log file and provide you insights as a huge String(JSON).

**Solution you can try implementing on your own**: http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/2.x/  to give you a headstart. Try to make this(Without UI,of course) with your log file. Believe me, you can learn a lot if you do this.

**Solution I'd prefer**: I'd suggest you implement https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana to aid you from your application tier. This also has steep learning curve for you if you are newbie. Good luck!